# Print Dialogue configuration to shell script

Tags: bash, xfce, hplip, xfce4-terminal, cups-lpd

I need help figuring out which program gets called with what all arguments when I print a file using the standard print dialogue with a specific configuration, so I can automate it using a script.

Env: xfce4 + ubuntu + bash

Printer is configured by hplip.

I want to print specific pages(not continuous), from a pdf file, 2 pages on one side, with certain formatting options as configured in the print dialogue below.

[image]

```
lp -o landscape -o fit-to-page -o media=A4 -o number-up=2 -o number-up-layout=lr -o page-ranges=320,289,321,300 ~/Documents/test.pdf 
lp: Bad page-ranges values 289-289.
```

The pdf file has more than 500 pages.
I want to incorporate a command which can print random pages I select 2 pages on 1 side of an A4 sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the lp command. That man page should help with finding all the options:

```
man lp
```

Comment: I tried but lp is not recognizing page rages of pdf.

Comment: So, `lp -P 1-3 blah.pdf` (print pages 1-3) doesn't work?

Comment: lp -o landscape -o fit-to-page -o media=A4 -o number-up=2 -o number-up-layout=lr -o page-ranges=320,289,321,300 ~/Documents/test.pdf 
    lp: Bad page-ranges values 289-289.

The pdf file has more than 500 pages.
I want to incorporate a command which can print random pages I select 2 pages on 1 side of an A4 sheet.

Comment: I tried with `-o page-ranges=320,289,321,300` and `-P 320,289,321,300` Both give the same error as mentioned above.